# Can I use "apply" in sense of "contact"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

It’s a classifieds app. Is it correct to use "brokers may **apply**"/"brokers may not **apply**" in sense of *contacting*? I mean does a broker **apply** when calling/emailing you to buy/rent your house, or is it better described with another word?

I simply cannot use *contact* because of an issue with that word's sense in the other-language version of the app. I tried but cannot find any other solution but ask here.

Comment: Good translation doesn't mean word for word translation. There's no reason you shouldn't use "contact" in the English version and some other word that isn't a cognate of *contact* in other languages.

Comment: Maybe it's translated automatically? When Chrome offers to translate a webpage I don't know that the site owner has any control over its word choice, for example.

@Maxim could you list a little more context? "Apply" is often used in classifieds but it implies they are being evaluated; an _applicant_ might get rejected.

Comment: @Photon Thanks! I was just wondering if "apply" is close by sense or no.

Comment: @Simone Thanks! No, I make 3 versions of the whole UI content without any automation like Google Translate. The context is: I sell a house. I don't want brokers to contact me because they have to ask fee from me or the buyer, either way it is financially worse than to sell directly to a buyer (yes, direct is common in this market). So I might reject ANY broker who contacts me, that's why I'll better choose *"Brokers may not apply"*.

Comment: @Simone (cont.) The other point: I wish to sell it ASAP or I don't be greedy for the commission; I check *"Brokers may apply*", so I get calls from brokers whose bargain I may deny or not, and from straight buyers whose bargain I may deny or not, as well.

Comment: @Maxim "apply" is perfect then. It sounds like Photon is right that you could just make the translations different, but I would use "apply" over "contact" anyway because it conveys "I may or may not accept" and "I am not _considering_ anyone". (not sure how straight buyers know they can offer too but I'm assuming you have that covered elsewhere)

Comment: @Simone Thanks a lot! Yes, the direct is covered elsewhere!

Comment: @Simone Won't you put your comment as an answer to get this question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apply** is often used in classifieds because it implies someone or something is being evaluated: an *applicant* might get rejected. *Contacting* someone refers to communication, like "Contact Alex for more info about our club"; less is expected of whoever is calling Alex, and they also definitely expect to hear back. "Apply" is better for your needs because it conveys "I may or may not accept"; conversely, "brokers may not apply" also lets users know "I am not *considering* anyone".